# ULIB.dll -- Any API documentation? How do you use it?

Tags: winapi

A little peeking at the disassembly of `Tree.com` (the command that shows a directory tree for a given folder) shows that almost all its functionality lies in `ULIB.dll`, the same file system library used by `ChkDsk.exe`.

Which is pretty funny, considering that enumerating a directory tree should be pretty straightforward with `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`...

So here come two questions:

1. Why does `Tree.com` use `ULIB.dll` for something so (seemingly) trivial? Why not just use standard traversal methods?
2. Is there *any* documentation whatsoever (official or unofficial) on the API of this library? The only thing I've found is [this](http://xpdll.nirsoft.net/ulib_dll.html) API listing, but is there more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it has a version of FindFirstFile that is declared as:

```
 void* __stdcall FindFirstFileW(class PATH const *, struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAW *)
```

Why use a C API when you've got a nice C++ implementation for it lying around.  It is an internal Microsoft library, not documented.

Comment: The trouble is, the library *bypasses* the file system, so it necessarily can't work for anything other than a few things like NTFS... it's a pretty high cost to pay, just to use a C++ API...

Comment: What do you base this assumption on?

Comment: I based it on the fact that `ChkDsk` also uses it... I guess I could be wrong but this seems likely. I'll go check it with ProcMon, though, to see if it's actually the case.

Comment: Never mind, you were right, I was wrong; it doesn't bypass the file system. But then it makes me wonder of what use it would be to ChkDsk...